# In VB: convert a string to a statement label

Tags: vb.net, type-conversion, label

In Visual Basic, is there a way to convert a string, entered on the command line, to a statement label? The intent is to execute only select portions of code. I'm working with a large program that includes many individual steps. For testing purposes I want to execute just one step without having to run through all of the previous steps.
I know how to extract the desired substring from the command line argument list.

So, given that string TestStep = "Step_3:"

somehow convert TestStep to point to label "Step_3:

```
GoTo TestStep
...
Step_1: 'do something
   GoTo Elsewhere
Step_2: 'do something else
   GoTo Elsewhere
Step_3: ' do the thing we want
   GoTo Elsewhere
Step_4: ' do other stuff
   GoTo Elsewhere
...
```

I've looked in "Visual Basic.NET" by Jesse Liberty and "VB.NET Language Pocket Reference" by Roman, Petrusha & Lomax without success.
Of course, just trying
GoTo TestStep  where TestStep is a string results in Visual Studio responding: Label "TestStep" not defined

Comment: Any particular reason why you're trying to do it using labels and `GoTo`s instead of something like a `Select Case` on the string?

Comment: Could you only find books written 20+ years ago? Is any of these using `GoTo` *extensively*, or *once in a while*, or *just once, to inform of the existence of the keyword*?

Comment: @Craig The reasons make me cringe even as I type them. I inherited these programs  which were 'translated' from code that ran on instrument controllers obsolete since the mid-80's. As such they extensively use labels/GoTo's and little else. What I have is a long stream of program steps that are grouped by labels and intended to run, one after the other collecting pass/fail results for each step. I have a down-and-dirty workaround but was striving for something even a little bit elegant. There is no funding for starting over and doing it right - only to get it working ASAP. Thanks

Comment: @Jimi Labels and GoTo's are used extensively. Someone in the past translated from an obsolete instrument controller language to Visual basic and preserved the primitive features of the old language instead of making use of the new(er). Regarding the books: I'm working with what I have available. Thanks.

Comment: I don't think there's an alternative in VB other than something dictionary-related or something based on Select Case.  Depending on the control flow, if you use Select Case, you might also need to include labels and `GoTo`s to drop down; but it ought to be possible to do without a massive amount of rewriting.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with a large and complicated `Select..Case` block that I didn't like due to potential complexity. I solved it by using `Action` variable type and a `Dictionary` of function pointers as below.

```
<TestMethod>
Public Sub TestMethod1()

    Dim stepsToExecute As Dictionary(Of String, Action) = CreateStepsArray()

    Dim testStep As Action = stepsToExecute("Sub1")
    testStep()
    testStep()
    testStep = stepsToExecute("Sub2")
    testStep()

    testStep = stepsToExecute("Sub3")
    testStep()

End Sub

Private Function CreateStepsArray() As Dictionary(Of String, Action)
    Dim functionsList As New Dictionary(Of String, Action) From
    {
        {"Sub1", AddressOf Sub1},
        {"Sub2", AddressOf Sub2},
        {"Sub3", AddressOf Sub3}
    }

    Return functionsList
End Function

Private Sub Sub1()
    Debug.WriteLine("Sub 1")
End Sub

Private Sub Sub2()
    Debug.WriteLine("Sub 2")
End Sub

Private Sub Sub3()
    Debug.WriteLine("Sub 3")
End Sub
```

When the test is run, it will produce this output:

```
Sub 1
Sub 1
Sub 2
Sub 3
```

Comment: Thanks for this. It's informative but not directly applicable due to circumstances. If I had more leeway with the existing code I would employ this solution.

Answer (score 0):

The lightest touch that I can think of would be something based on `Select Case` which would probably also require labels and `GoTo`s to jump between cases.  My idea is that if you started with something like this (not actually executable VB code, more like a VB-Fortran hybrid pseudocode):

```vb
Dim target As String
Dim label As Object

Assign target To Label 'Hypothetical nonexistent Fortran-style "assigned GoTo"

GoTo Label

Qwerty:
' Stuff to do under one label

Dvorak:
' Stuff to do under another

Uiop:
' Stuff to do under a third
```

Then maybe it could convert to something like this:

```vb
Dim target As String

Select Case target
    Case "Qwerty"
        'Stuff
        'If (and only if) it should fall through
        GoTo Dvorak

    Case "Dvorak"
Dvorak:
        'Stuff
        'Optional fall-through
        GoTo Uiop

    Case "Uiop"
Uiop:
        'Stuff
End Select
```